# Extracting sql insert with sed, line cuts

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, mysql

I've been reading on stackoverflow about the use of `sed` for extracting data from sql dumps, being more accurate, the final purpose is to extract inserts for an specific table in order to restore only that table.

I’m using this:

```
sed -n '/LOCK TABLES `TABLE_NAME`/,/UNLOCK TABLES/p' dump.sql > output.sql
```

The problem that I’m having is that we have inserts on 1 line that are more than 50Mb long, so while extracting the insert, the output gets cut before the end of the line.
like:

```
......
(4
3458,'0Y25565137SEOEJ','001','PREPAR',1330525937741,
NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
(43459,'666
```

I tried to use `awk` and even simple `grep` and the result is the same, the line gets cut.

Edit: Im using this on a sql dump from mysql and the system I'm working on is a Centos 5.2

Comment: no, the dump is 85Gb long and this insert is on the first 10% of the file.

Comment: Have you tried this on another machine? 50 MB long lines are not so huge. Even Cygwin can handle lines about 100 MB on windows.

Comment: Maybe you should cut out `10Gb` using `dd`. Then do command on this smaller file.

Comment: I've put the command on a script and launch it with bash -x just to see if any error pop up, ill explore the "dd" option for this specific scenario but for future uses its not usefull due to the fact that I'm not going to know always where the inserts that we need are.

Comment: Hi Gergely, I'm going to try on other machines as well.

Comment: do `head` and `tail` also cut the line if you extract it manually? If not, you could run `awk` to print the line ranges & pipe to `xargs` to  extract the ranges using `head` and `tail`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try awk and see if it's better (I think so) :

```
awk '/LOCK TABLES `TABLE_NAME`/,/UNLOCK TABLES/' dump.sql > output.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

But if it's a dump file created with `exp`, you can import only the needed tables with

```
imp user/pass tables=table1,table2 ...
```

Comment: Yes, in an edit after my answer. Which I did not predicted, sorry.